# decrypt .ts segments from m3u8 with python

Tags: python, encryption, aes, m3u8

Why does my code not decrypt the `ts` segment?

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import requests as req
import os
import m3u8
with req.session() as req:
    m3u = m3u8.load('https://svt1-a.akamaized.net/se/svt1/d132b755-8088-475e-91df-2c8f2de9cf6c/hls-v6/v6.m3u8')
    key_url = m3u.keys[0].absolute_uri
    seg = m3u.segments[0].absolute_uri
    key = ''
    for chunk in req.get(key_url,stream=True):
        key+=chunk
    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, os.urandom(16))
    data = ''
    for chunk in req.get(seg, stream=True):
        data+=chunk
    data = cipher.decrypt(data)
    with open('ulk.ts','wb') as fil:
        fil.write(data)
```

The m3u8 url is:

> https://svt1-a.akamaized.net/se/svt1/d132b755-8088-475e-91df-2c8f2de9cf6c/hls-v6/v6.m3u8

Code from the m3u8:

```
EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:4
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:4
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:220662
#EXTINF:3.20000,
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="../key-d132b755-8088-475e-91df-2c8f2de9cf6c.ts"
v6-220662.ts
#EXTINF:3.20000,
v6-220663.ts
#EXTINF:3.20000,
v6-220664.ts
#EXTINF:3.20000,
v6-220665.ts
#EXTINF:3.20000,
v6-220666.ts
#EXTINF:3.20000,
v6-220667.ts
#EXTINF:3.20000,
v6-220668.ts
#EXTINF:3.20000,
v6-220669.ts
#EXTINF:3.20000,
v6-220670.ts
#EXTINF:3.20000,
v6-220671.ts
```

Keystring:

> 'PB{\xf1\xb9\xf9.\xb7\x1d\xeb\x95\x8f=\xcd\x93\xce'

Comment: trying to reach the given URL ends with `Access Denied`

Comment: @Skandix I have now edit the question with some code from the m3u8. It's an geoblock. If you use some swedish proxy or vpn you can connect

Comment: You can't decrypt a file using a random IV, you have to use the same IV that was used to encrypt the file. Often the encryption IV is prepended to the cipher. I have no idea what format being used here, you'd have to provide some additional info.

Comment: @JamesKPolk Ok? I have added the key from the keyfile

Answer (score 0):

I have a perfect solution for your little problem.
Your code is great but it need some few little fixes - Than it will nicely run.

Python venv:

```
 - python3 -m venv Your-Python-VEnviroment-Name-env
 - cd Your-Python-VEnviroment-Name-env
 - source bin/activate
```

- Follow the Steps 1..5
- deactivate

Step 01: Module-List must to install into python venv:

```
 - python3 -m pip install m3u8
 - python3 -m pip install requests
 - python3 -m pip install pycryptodome
```

Step 02: Create a file `GetSegments.py`
Step 03: Fill it with the below code-boxes

List of imports:

```
import os
import m3u8
import requests
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
```

Set a own RequestsClient to get https to work.

```
class MyOwnReqClient():
    def download(self, uri, timeout=None, headers={}, verify_ssl=True):
        result = requests.get(uri, timeout=timeout, headers=headers)
        return result.text, result.url
```

Set m3u8.load correctly with your own RequestsClient.Class.

```
#Other headers should you look at F12 ;-)
headers = {'host':'Your-Data-Here', 'User-Agent':'Your-Browser-User-Agent-Here-VERY-IMPORTANT'}
url = 'https://YOUR.URL.M3U8.Encrypted-ts-segments.HERE'
m3u = m3u8.load(url, http_client=MyOwnReqClient(), headers=headers)
```

Set key variable correctly.

```
key_url = m3u.keys[0].absolute_uri
key = []
for chunk in req.get(url=key_url,stream=True,headers=headers,method="get"):
    key.append(chunk)
```

Set the correct IV for crypto.

```
lines = str(m3u.segments[0]).split('\n')
IV = lines[0].split("IV=")[1]
#convert into bytes and remove the first 2 chars
IV = bytes.fromhex(IV.replace("0x",""))
```

Init crypto.

```
cipher = AES.new(key[0], AES.MODE_CBC, IV=IV)
```

At least you must to change your data store routine.

```
#Get each segment of m3u8-file        
for single_segment in m3u.segments:
    #Get correct URL for ts-file
    download_url = single_segment.absolute_uri

    #Counter 1..n
    num = 1

    #Write bytes into a file
    with open('Filename.part' + str(num) + '.ts', 'wb') as seg_ts:
        #Get all chunks of current part-file
        for chunk in requests.request(url=download_url, stream=True, headers=headers, method="get"):
            #decrypt it and write it into the file
            seg_ts.write(cipher.decrypt(chunk))

        #Counter increase for the next part number
        num += 1
```

Step 04: Save the file and try it.

Step 05: `python3 GetSegments.py`

I hope it helps you and all others.
I could not sleep if the python script not done and works.

I hope I have not any wrong write typoos... ;-)